# Thread pending in java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:956)

Tags: java

I found there are 4 threads pending here for 1 hours, it doesn't make sense the thread pending in 
java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:956)

here is the thread dump segment

```
        "task-scheduler-8" #135571 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe1a0cf9800 nid=0x27c9 runnable [0x00007fe0d3e07000]

           java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

            at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:956)

            at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)

            at com.company.app.company.transformPdfTransformer.findSoldTo(CovesPdfTransformer.java:147)

            at com.company.app.company.transformPdfTransformer.findSoldTo(CovesPdfTransformer.java:128)

            at com.company.app.company.transformPdfTransformer.formatText(CovesPdfTransformer.java:21)

            at com.company.app.component.transformer.pdfbox.AbsPdfTransformer.transformer(AbsPdfTransformer.java:15)

            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3159.invoke(Unknown Source)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

            at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:117)
```

here is the line "CovesPdfTransformer.java:147"

```
 lineTrim = line.replaceAll(" ", "").trim();
```

Comment: We restarted JVM and the issue solved.

Comment: If you look at `Matcher.java:956`, you'll see it's doing work (well, ready to work as the thread is `RUNNABLE`). If you think it's not finishing its work fast enough, either the system was overloaded or there was bad input that made it crawl to a halt.

Comment: In general, the fact that a thread is pending doesn't mean that it's that thread's fault, quite the contrary. It's the ones that are running that cause the overload that causes this thread to pend.